# How to build Mac host in visualstudio using xamarin

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I installed xamarin in windows 7 Home Basic. I need to connect Mac host in visual studio, I get the ios settings to build, but its not host automatically.
  On the Xamarin guides, they informed Craigs-MacBook.local but I cant get the host in my laptop. I simply struggled
  Can you please explain me what can i do further to host Mac in windows PC to run iPhone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Contact their support team, they will be quick to help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 8):

You need to install Xamarin on your Mac, then you have to activate your Xamarin Studio in both computers (Mac and Windows). To do this you need to:

1. **Create a Xamarin account** and set it or **link it** to your Visual Studio(Windows) and Xamarin Studio(Mac) IDEs so they can interact. This is Via **Tools > Xamarin Account**. It is not necessary to buy a license since you can start with the trial version of Xamarin.
2. **Create a Test or whatever Project** on both IDEs in order to be prompted to **activate your Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio**.
3. Once you have "activated" both your IDEs, you have to link Visual Studio to your iOS Xamarin via: **Tools > Options > Xamarin > iOS Settings.**

And that's all.

Maybe you can't set your Host Mac Xamarin.IOs in Visual Studio because you haven't activated your iOS Xamarin Studio in your Mac, in order to do that, in your Mac Xamarin Studio **create a project from a template that utilizes network connections**, and you'll be prompted to activate your Xamarin Studio. In **Windows Visual Studio** you have to **create any project** and you'll be prompted to activate your Visual Studio.

Also your **SDKs on both machines may be out of synch**, so you'll have to download some updates on your Mac and Win to synchronize both IDEs and SDKs in order for them to work together.

Also you have to **install your Xamarin and Visual Studio in this order**:

1. First, Install Visual Studio in Windows.
2. Second, Xamarin Studio in Mac and Windows.
3. Finally Link your Mac and Win through Visual Studio.

Also it is **recommended to have a Windows  Pro version** since you can't use the Windows Phone Emulator on a Home (Core) Version of Windows 8 because you won't be able to install Hyper-V which is needed to run this Emulator. Furthermore, you'll need a **Visual Studio Pro or higher** version to link your Xamarin to Visual Studio.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @Wenitz, well I need Mac machine to connect Xamarin iOS

Comment: That's right. You're welcome @charulatha, and even you are able to develop iOS on Windows, you need a Mac machine in order to do that, because the iOS SDK can't be outside a Mac machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had to follow the instructions here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/troubleshooting/offline.pdf

Basically I was missing:

- Open spotlight on the mac
- Type "xamarin build host"
- Launch, and it shows a pairing prompt
- I followed the on-screen instructions, using a pin to associate my windows machine